# Catching Error in pipe() method of an Observable - rxjs/Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, rxjs

I refactored my http layer to go from a promised-based implementation to observables using `rxjs`. The problem that I am facing is that the code crashes whenever server response is `400` or `500`,

```
Axios.request(config).pipe(map(((response: AxiosResponse) => response), catchError(e => {
    return new Observable(e);
})));
```

The problem I am facing is that the error is not being handled by the `catchError` callback. I am looking for a way in which the error is handled by the `catchError` callback so that the response can be handled gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your problem is this but you can do this:

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';

Axios.request(config).pipe(map(((response: AxiosResponse) => response), 
catchError(() => EMPTY)));
```

> `EMPTY` is an object that is imported from rxjs libaray.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to turn the `error` notification to `next` notification so you need to use `return of(e)` eventually `EMPTY` if you want to suppress the error.

`new Observable(e)` is probably what throws the error in your case because the parameter passed to `Observable` needs to be a function which `e` is not in this  case.